# Actor not catching exception in Test even if thrown

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

My `Actor` looks like

```
object LogProcessorActor {
  def props(f: () => Unit): Props = Props(new LogProcessorActor(f))
}

class LogProcessorActor(f: () => Unit) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = LoggingReceive {
    case StartLogReaderDisruptor => f()
      sender ! StartedLogReaderDisruptor
  }
}
```

and my `test` looks like

```
  it must "fail with method throws exception" in {
    val f: () => Unit = () => 2/0
    val logProcessorRef = TestActorRef[LogProcessorActor](LogProcessorActor.props(f), name = "logProcessorSad")
    intercept[ArithmeticException] {
      logProcessorRef ! StartLogReaderDisruptor
    }
  }
```

I see in logs that the exception is thrown

```
[DEBUG] [06/02/2015 19:25:44.598] [ScalaTest-run] [EventStream(akka://logProcessorActorSystem)] logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
[DEBUG] [06/02/2015 19:25:44.599] [ScalaTest-run] [EventStream(akka://logProcessorActorSystem)] Default Loggers started
02 Jun 2015 19:25:44,601 [DEBUG] [logProcessorActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] akka.event.EventStream| logger log1-Slf4jLogger started
02 Jun 2015 19:25:44,603 [DEBUG] [logProcessorActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] akka.event.EventStream| Default Loggers started02 Jun 2015 19:25:44,782 [ERROR] [logProcessorActorSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy| / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.shn.lp.LogProcessorActorSpec$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$4.apply$mcV$sp(LogProcessorActorSpec.scala:18)
    at com.shn.lp.LogProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(LogProcessorActor.scala:16)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at com.shn.lp.LogProcessorActor.aroundReceive(LogProcessorActor.scala:14)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
```

But still my test fails as

```
Expected exception java.lang.ArithmeticException to be thrown, but no exception was thrown.
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.shn.lp.LogProcessorActorSpec$$anonfun$3 at (LogProcessorActorSpec.scala:20)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Expected exception java.lang.ArithmeticException to be thrown, but no exception was thrown.
```

I even tried the strategy mentioned in [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html#The_Way_In-Between__Expecting_Exceptions), but I still get the same result.

What am I doing incorrect?

Comment: user actor `receive`,  which is available in `TestActorRef` instead of `tell` or `!`.

Comment: @johny you should provide that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

An uncaught exception thrown in an actor's receive block will not be handled by the sender.  It will be handled according to the actor's supervision hierarchy.  The parent actor will deal with the child according to its supervisor strategy.

This is covered in the *Actors and exceptions* section of the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/scala/actors.html#Actors_and_exceptions